# Needs to run the variable after http response

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise

I have a es6 class from there i will be getting user name and contact detail. In the code itself i mentioned the issue.
 From the `user1.getUserName()` function i will be getting `Mr.undefined`. I know the reason because this line `let str = 'Mr.' + username.name` executes before the http call. Needs to run the variable after http request finished loading.
 I tried a lot couldn't find the correct solution. I think we can solve this with `promise` but i don't know how to achieve it.

```
const http = require('http');

class User {
    httpRequest () {
    http.get(url, function (resp) {
        let data = ''
      resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk
      })
      resp.on('end', () => {
        return JSON.parse(data)
      })
    })
  }

  getUserName () {
    let username = this.httpRequest()

    // needs to run after the http response

    let str = 'Mr.' + username.name
    return str;
  }

  getContactetail () {
    let contactDetail = this.httpRequest()
    let str = 'My address is ' + contactDetail.address
    return str;
  }
}

let user1 = new User();
console.log(user1.getUserName());
```

Comment: Now you have to create the promise yourself, how about a library where this is already done for you. Like axios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also reject the promise inside httpRequest method on error.

```
class User {
    httpRequest () {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            http.get(url, function (resp) {
                let data = ''
              resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk
              })
              resp.on('end', () => {
                resolve(JSON.parse(data));
              })
            })

        })
  }

  getUserName async () {
    let username = await this.httpRequest()

    // needs to run after the http response

    let str = 'Mr.' + username.name
    return str;
  }

  getContactetail () {
    let contactDetail = this.httpRequest()
    let str = 'My address is ' + contactDetail.address
    return str;
  }
}

let user1 = new User();
console.log(user1.getUserName());
```

Comment: Initially i tried with the same, at the time it didn't worked due to some type error since i using typescript, anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: you can mark it as correct answer if it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Example POST method implementation

```
try {
  const data = await postData('http://example.com/answer', { answer: 42 });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // JSON-string from `response.json()` call
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
}

async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrer: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *client
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return await response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}
```